# How does Github detect mirrored repositories?

Tags: git, github

Take a look at the Github repositories here:

https://github.com/apache/

They are marked as mirrors and even the source mirror URL is mentioned.

I want to do the same (Mirroring some SVN/Git/Mercurial repo on Github) but when I do it following a mirror howto like [this](http://exyr.org/2011/git-mirrors/) or [this](http://jnrbsn.com/2010/11/how-to-mirror-a-subversion-repository-on-github) then my repositories are not marked as mirrors. They appear as normal repositories instead.

So what's the trick here? Is this some special feature you have to pay for on Github?

Comment: As far as I know this is done manually. But I could be wrong

Comment: why not ask their tech support. They are usually very good. Don't forget to post the solution here ;-)

Comment: I think the repo has some meta info which they are reading, but I am just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "marked as mirror" thing is a github feature, not a git one.  Presumably they have some internal framework that makes managing all their mirrors easier.  You can't run code on their servers, so you can't manage a mirror in the same way.

Comment: So is it stuff only github staff can set up?